# how to render react-toolbox menu

Tags: react-toolbox

How does one render a react-toolbox Menu component? There are no examples in the documentation. Or, rather, the example uses the IconMenu wrapper, which is unusable if you need to pass in the `active` property.

When I render a Menu, it is always rendered as active, regardless of the `active` property. It could be a css problem, but I'm unable to follow how IconMenu applies css, and it's interactions with ThemeProvider.